# How to update a column in Core Data Table

Tags: ios, core-data

I am developing a iOS app in which I am using Core Data. I am downloading data from a web service. Initially I have a table in which there is a field "to". When data for one table is completed, I want to update "to" field of the table with a count of data that have been downloaded.

This is what I've used so far:

```
NSString *str;
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Resume" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]]; 
NSFetchRequest *request2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request2 setEntity:entityDesc];
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects=[[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *info in objects) { 
   str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info valueForKey:@"to"]]; 
   int tableCount=[str intValue]+countValue;
   NSLog(@"tableCount===%d",tableCount);
   [info setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tableCount] forKey:@"to"];
}
```

Comment: We've edited your question into shape with your follow-on information, but you might still need to tell us what isn't working right in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either in the last line of your FOR loop or AFTER the FOR loop add the following line to save your changes in Core Data:

```
[[self managedObjectContext] save];
```